# How to use custom tokens for material web library on a vue 3 application

Tags: vue.js, material-ui, material-design, figma, design-tokens

I am someone new to design system, i want to use custom tokens/variables for [material web](https://m3.material.io/develop/web) library on a vue 3 application.

First of all i have the token design (color, typography, effects, layouts) on figma. How to download the tokens. And how to use that tokens to override the default token of material web on a UI framework like vue 3.

I see currently material web library is in very early stage, can it accepts custom theming for color, typography, effects and layouts. Otherwise is there any other material 3 library that is available to use.

I am able to use the default themes by following this https://github.com/material-components/material-web/blob/main/docs/quick-start.md